Trying to connect to MySQL 8.0 via telnet, but getting weird characters
I'm trying to test connections into MySQL8.0 but there are some unexpected results.
After using telnet [ip] 3306, i get:
enter image description here
I try to insert the password but it just ends the communication. I believe what failed was the authentication step, since i'm not getting the same communication error like before.
Thanks in advance.

I already granted permissions to root@[Ip]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0 already on my.cnf
I can use python to connect to the server. However, I wanted to be able to communicate via other ways too.


you must use the mysql client to connect to the MySQL Server

The MySQL protocol is binary, not intended for interactive use with telnet.

@BerndBuffen I was trying to simulate how someone from the organization could also connect to the database, so I was trying to use telnet to check if the connection was online, but then that happened. In fact I am using SQLalchemy now, and it thankfully works

@Barmar The idea here was to check the connection only, so I could then proceed with client installation on other computers

Your approach works with text-based protocols, like http, but will not work with a binary protocol, like mysql's communication protocol. You have to use a mysql client that can work with mysql server. If you really want to get deep in communication with mysql, then use its c/c++ API.

Thank you all for the answers, I'll try to find another way!
